# How to sync start of two cyclic tasks (swift)

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

I have two loops that must run periodically.

One of the loop (A) has a constant duration and is scheduled with high accuracy, no problem.

The other loop (B) can have a variable duration. Much shorter or much longer than duration of A.
But whatever B’s duration, I want to start next B cycle at the start of the next A cycle.
If B is much shorter than A, then it must wait next A’start.
If B is much longer than A, then, when it completes, whatever the number of A cycles that occurred, it shall wait and start at next A’s start.

I first thought of using a semaphore. A would signal the semaphore at its start, while B would wait for it at it start.
This works if B is shorter than A.

But if B is longer, the semaphore gets increment (maybe over 1), and I don’t get B to wait, it restarts immediately at its end and starts-sync is lost.

Any solution (preferably with GCD, but any solution would do) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have an idea of using GCD and semaphores as a solution, I feel something like this could also be achieved with `OperationQueues`

I like the use of `OperationQueues` for your use case because you can add dependencies like in the situation when B is longer and has to wait for the current A to finish.

Here is a small experiment I ran, please have a look if this suits your use case:

**Logic with comments**

```
// A duration is fixed at 5
let aDuration: UInt32 = 5
    
// Control B's duration between 1 and 15
let maxBDuration: UInt32 = 15

// Initialize an Operation queue
let operationQueue = OperationQueue()

// Operations A and B which will be initialized
// before being added to a queue
var operationA: BlockOperation!
var operationB: BlockOperation!

// Counters to identify which loop A and B currently
// are in, just for our identification
var aLoopCount = 0
var bLoopCount = 0

// When to stop the experiment
let experimentCount = 10

// Launch the A loop
runALoop()

// Launch the B loop simultaneously specifying
// it is first launch, you will see why soon
runBLoop(isFirstLaunch: true)

// B is identical to A with a few small differences
private func runBLoop(isFirstLaunch: Bool = false)
{
    operationB = BlockOperation
    {
        self.bLoopCount += 1
        
        // The duration of b varies as you mentioned
        let duration = UInt32.random(in: 1...self.maxBDuration)
        
        print("Operation B\(self.bLoopCount) started, Duration: \(duration)s")
        
        sleep(duration)
        
        print("Operation B\(self.bLoopCount) done")
        
        if self.bLoopCount != self.experimentCount
        {
            self.runBLoop()
        }
    }
    
    // Check if we are not in the first launch
    if !isFirstLaunch
    {
        // Add a dependency of the newly initialize B loop
        // To the currently running A so it starts only when
        // the current A finishes
        operationB.addDependency(operationA)
    }
    
    operationQueue.addOperation(operationB)
}
```

**The Output**

```
Operation A1 started, Duration: 5s
Operation B1 started, Duration: 14s
Operation A1 done
Operation A2 started, Duration: 5s
Operation A2 done
Operation A3 started, Duration: 5s
Operation B1 done
Operation A3 done
Operation A4 started, Duration: 5s
Operation B2 started, Duration: 13s
Operation A4 done
Operation A5 started, Duration: 5s
Operation A5 done
Operation A6 started, Duration: 5s
Operation B2 done
Operation A6 done
Operation A7 started, Duration: 5s
Operation B3 started, Duration: 8s
Operation A7 done
Operation A8 started, Duration: 5s
Operation B3 done
Operation A8 done
Operation B4 started, Duration: 4s
Operation A9 started, Duration: 5s
Operation B4 done
Operation A9 done
Operation B5 started, Duration: 3s
Operation A10 started, Duration: 5s
Operation B5 done
Operation A10 done
Operation B6 started, Duration: 7s
Operation B6 done
Operation B7 started, Duration: 5s
Operation B7 done
Operation B8 started, Duration: 13s
Operation B8 done
Operation B9 started, Duration: 3s
Operation B9 done
Operation B10 started, Duration: 8s
Operation B10 done
```

**Conclusions**

1. The most interesting data to analyse is up until **Operation A10 done** as after this A no longer runs
2. This output sequence shows you the case when B is longer:

```
Operation A1 started, Duration: 5s
Operation B1 started, Duration: 14s
Operation A1 done
Operation A2 started, Duration: 5s
Operation A2 done
Operation A3 started, Duration: 5s
Operation B1 done
Operation A3 done
Operation A4 started, Duration: 5s
Operation B2 started, Duration: 13s
```

As you see `B1` starts when `A1` starts and ends before `A3` is done but it waits till `A3` before it starts again with `A4`

3. Later on in the sequence, it also shows you what happens when B is shorter:

```
Operation B4 started, Duration: 4s
Operation A9 started, Duration: 5s
Operation B4 done
Operation A9 done
Operation B5 started, Duration: 3s
Operation A10 started, Duration: 5s
Operation B5 done
Operation A10 done
Operation B6 started, Duration: 7s
```

In this situation, Both B4 and B5 end before the current A operation is finished but they wait

4. I feel this could work for you because it does not matter if B is shorter or longer than A because **the next B** will always be dependant on the **current A** to finish executing before starting.

Comment: Impressive ! Thanks !